# Cocoapods linker error when running app from Xcode project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I tried installing some Cocoapods based on some instructions online and the whole process went as described. But I now get an error:

> ld: framework not found Pods_Happ
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried installing a pod called "WCLShineButton". I think it has something to do with my app's framework because the "Pods_Happ.framework" is red:

[Pods_Happ.framework red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Uii.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the .xcodeproj file and open the .xcworkspace file in Xcode instead.

CocoaPods wraps your Xcode project (.xcodeproj) into an Xcode workspace. After that you should always work with the workspace instead of the project.

Comment: Ah geez that did it.  Thank you so much, saved me days of scrutiny.